# A Javascript Function that can tell me whether two people's first name, last name, and email are identical or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a Javascript function that can accept any two person objects and return true if they're exactly the same( for example if firstName, lastName, and email values all match) and false if they are not identical.  This is what I've got so far but I dont have any of the logic yet because I am not sure if it would be done with an if else statement or something else.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Question 6</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script>
var person1 = {
firstName: "Mike",
lastName: "Smith",
email: "msmith@yahoo.com"
};

var person2 = {
firstName: "John",
lastName: "Smith",
email: "jsmith@yahoo.com"
};

$(document).ready (function comparePersons(person1, person2) {

if (person1.firstName !== person2.firstName)
    return false;
if (person1.lastName !== person2.lastName)
    return false;
if (person1.email !== person2.email)
    return false;

 else
 return true;

});
$("#output").html(value);

if (return  true)
string "True";

else (return  false)
string "False";

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="output">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can the objects contains other attributes ?

Comment: They can but I am not going to give them any

Comment: Please see the beginning of my response below. You have typos in your code, and you're creating local variables that overwrite the `person#` objects passed in to the compare function. In your latest edit, `person1` is overwritten entirely, so your comparisons will not involve what's passed in. Also, you `return true` (and stop the function) before you try to change `$('#output").htmlI()`. You can't pass `return` to the `html()` function that way either. You need to pass it some string value.

Comment: So where would I put the String for the return? I fixed the typos.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: in a shorter way (especially if you want to compare more stuff), we just set an array of all the attribute we want to compare, and loop through them:

```
function areTheyTheSame(p1, p2) {
  var criterias = ['email', 'firstName', 'lastName'];

  for (var i=0; i<criterias.length; i++) {
    if (p1[criterias[i]] !== p2[criterias[i]])
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(areTheyTheSame(person1, person2));
```

---

FIRST ANSWER:
I would say the best way to do it would be a function like:

```
function areTheyTheSame(p1, p2) {
  if (p1.email !== p2.email)
    return false;
  if (p1.firstName !== p2.firstName)
    return false;
  if (p1.lastName !== p2.lastName)
    return false;

  return true;
}
console.log(areTheyTheSame(person1, person2));
```

The purpose is to return early in the function. As soon as we know that they are not the same person (and the email is probably the easiest way to know it) we can return from the function.

Comment: I have edited what I originally had as my question because I know I am close now. I am having a hard time of how to get the return value to display

Comment: Good answer but you can make it even shorter and get rid of the explicit loop by using `Array.prototype.reduce`: `criterias.reduce(function(res, prop) { return res && p1[prop] === p2[prop] }, true)`

Comment: Well, the purpose is not to lost the person who asks. But good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You have typos in a few places - should be "person" not "peson"
2. If you're passing in 2 "person" arguments to the function, you shouldn't create new local "person" variables within the function anyway - since they have the same name they'll overwrite/conflict with what gets passed in. In your current code, you're not comparing 2 things passed in, you're only comparing `person2` to the local version of `person1` you define inside the function.
3. You also have 2 `return` statements. The 1st one causes the function to stop where it is, so the line where you try to display to `#output` doesn't even get hit.
4. You can't put `return` in the `html()` function like that. It needs to be HTML or a string.

To the original question: 
In JavaScript, you can access object properties using dot notation or brackets. 
You can also compare strings directly using "===" (unlike some languages). This should work in your case since everything you're comparing seems to be strings.

So if you want to compare firstName, lastName, and email, one option is to combine those 3 conditions in a single `if` statement...

```
if (person1.email === person2.email && person1.lastName === person2.lastName && person1.firstName === person2.firstName) {
 //Success!
}
else {
//Fail! 
}
```

This will fail and return at whichever condition fails first, so if you order them in decreasing chance of matching, you'll figure out sooner whether or not there's a match. But, this is a rather long & complicated conditional statement. It'd be cleaner and more manageable to break them up.

Alternatively, especially if you want to add or compare more properties in the future ... see Cohars answer for the other approach I was going to write, but now don't have to :)

Comment: Yes, the `if` will also return early. But that's a pretty long condition I think.

Comment: I know - I was on the way to explaining it another way but you beat me to it :)

Comment: I have made another edit. I feel like I am getting closer but have to leave soon.  If you could critique what is wrong with how I am getting "True" or "False" to display I would appreciate it. I am not good at programming as you can see. I have the function correct I believe I just don't know how to get it to dispay.